# How to find video files with length less than 30 minutes on windows 10

Tags: windows, video, windows-search

I want to search for all video files that have a length that is less than 30 minutes, so that I can delete them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a direct approach to this, but here is a workaround which should help:

In an explorer, type `kind:=video` in the search bar. This will find you all the videos on your computer. Then right-click on the column headings bar, select "More" and add the field "Length" to the list. You can then sort by length and select those that are shorter than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Open *File Explorer* (icon looks like a manila folder).

Go to the folder where your videos are stored.

Hover your mouse over the headings line where it says Name, Title, Type, etc. (It will turn light blue in color), right click.
A drop down will appear from which you can add columns to the way your files are presented. Click on `'Length'`.
Once the length column is present, click its heading to sort the list by length.
Delete each file less than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In the explorer file search box (usually in the right upper corner)
enter:
**Duration: < 18000000000**
Where the literal string "Duration" is **locale-dependent**. The name of the column for "duration" in Explorer details view is expected. With German locale it would be "Länge".

The value **18000000000** stands for **30 minutes**, because this value seems to be expressed in a **unit of 100 nanoseconds** (or a differently put tenth of a micro-second). Which is a second divided by 10^7.
**One minute would be expressed as 600000000**.
**One second would be expressed as 10000000**.
So one minute and one second would be 610000000. 1m30s would be  900000000 etc.
You can enter this number with thousands separators, which are again locale dependent.
Not too intuitive ;)